# Files don't load into Webapp or Website

Tags: html, windows, yeoman

I have a huge problem: Everytime I want to include a file in any kind of web project it does not work because for some reason all paths I put into the (for example) html file as a link or script tag don't load because it seams like the relative paths are not working. If I open the html as a file in chrome, it's actually looking for the file in the root directory of the drive and not in the folder of the html. The same error appears if I try to use any kind of local webserver (real hosted server works). I also downloaded any kind of demo projects and installed a few yeoman generators and the all got the same problem: Chrome says that it cannot find the file or it's just an empty file.

That's the reason why I think the problem has to do with my own pc. Any ideas what could cause this issue?

Comment: Check for the following tag in your HTML: `<base href...>`. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp. Make sure it's not set to `/` if you're testing locally. If your URLs for includes start with `/`, they will go to the absolute path. If you want relative path, drop the `/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your URLs for includes start with `/`, they will go to the absolute path. When testing locally from your filesystem, this is the root drive (such as `C:\`). If you want relative path, drop the `/`.

Also, check for the following tag in your HTML: `<base href...>` See http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp. Make sure it's not set to `/` if you're testing locally.

This `<base>` tag helps shorten potentially lengthy relative paths. For example:

`<script src="resources/production/script.js"></script>`

If you add `<base href="resources/production/">` to the `<head>` element, you can shorten your script tag to `src="script.js"`

**Beware ALL relative paths will have their root at `resources/production/` if you define it in your `<base>` tag**